# C# How to convert an Expression<Func<SomeType>> to an Expression<Func<OtherType>>

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, lambda, repository-pattern, expression-trees

I have used C# expressions before based on lamdas, but I have no experience composing them by hand. Given an `Expression<Func<SomeType, bool>> originalPredicate`, I want to create an `Expression<Func<OtherType, bool>> translatedPredicate`.

In this case SomeType and OtherType have the same fields, but they are not related (no inheritance and not based on a common interface).

Background: I have a repository implementation based on LINQ to SQL. I project the LINQ to SQL entities to my Model entities, to keep my model in POCO. I want to pass expressions to the repository (as a form of specifications) but they should be based on the model entities. But I can't pass those expressions to the data context, since it expects expressions based on the LINQ to SQL entities.

Comment: The response is in this topic:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4601844/expression-tree-copy-or-convert

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With `Expression`, the simplest way is with a conversion **expression**:

```
class Foo {
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
class Bar {
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        Expression<Func<Foo, bool>> predicate =
            x => x.Value % 2 == 0;
        Expression<Func<Bar, Foo>> convert =
            bar => new Foo { Value = bar.Value };

        var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Bar), "bar");
        var body = Expression.Invoke(predicate,
              Expression.Invoke(convert, param));
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Bar, bool>>(body, param);

        // test with LINQ-to-Objects for simplicity
        var func = lambda.Compile();
        bool withOdd = func(new Bar { Value = 7 }),
             withEven = func(new Bar { Value = 12 });
    }
}
```

Note however that this will be supported differently by different providers. EF might not like it, for example, even if LINQ-to-SQL does.

The other option is to rebuild the expression tree **completely**, using reflection to find the corresponding members. Much more complex.

Comment: I'm hoping L2EF likes this because I am converting an expression from an interface to the concrete class, and to return the results as an IQueryable<Interface> ... do you think there is a way to reduce overhead?

Comment: +1: this gets me going the right way I think. Even so, I've definitely learned something new. I am getting a missing relationship from EF. I'll work on it a bit more before I pose a new question. I am wondering if I need to attach the tables via the EntityCollection method...

Answer (score 3):

There is one other way I have found, that also includes wrapping your original delegate.

```
Func<T, object> ExpressionConversion<U>(Expression<Func<T, U>> expression)
{
    Expression<Func<T, object>> g = obj => expression.Compile().Invoke(obj);
    return g.Compile();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no implicit way to do the translation. You have to wrap your existing delegate inside a lambda that creates a new type from the argument type:

```
var translatedPredicate = x => originalPredicate(OtherTypeFromSomeType(x))
```

Where `OtherTypeFromSomeType` creates the `OtherType` instance from the `SomeType` argument.

Comment: The question was about expressions, not delegates. You can't use this approach to invoke a sub-expression; it is more complex.

Comment: Oops, didn't read carefully enough. Anyway, the technique is basically the same, expressions just require more work (even though technically my code would still work after first compiling `originalPredicate`, and using `Expression<…>` instead of `var` ;-)).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had the same inconvenience, the problem was that I was using AutoMapper to pass information from one class to another and in this case @Marc-Gravell's solution did not work for me with AutoMapper, but doing some research I found that AutoMapper can convert `Expression<Func<OrderLineDTO, bool>>` to `Expression<Func<OrderLine, bool>>`

```
public class OrderLine
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int OrderId { get; set; }
  public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}

public class OrderLineDTO
{
  public int Id { get; set; }
  public int OrderId { get; set; }
  public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
}
```

The AutoMapper configuration would be the following

```
var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
{
    cfg.AddExpressionMapping();

    cfg.CreateMap<OrderLine, OrderLineDTO>();
    cfg.CreateMap<OrderLineDTO, OrderLine>();
});

var mapper = config.CreateMapper();
```

And finally, perform the conversion

```
Expression<Func<OrderLineDTO, bool>> expression = e => e.OrderId == 102;

Expression<Func<OrderLine, bool>> convertedExpression = mapper.Map<Expression<Func<OrderLine, bool>>>(expression);
```

This code depends on `AutoMapper` and `AutoMapper.Extensions.ExpressionMapping`

For more information, you can see the documentation of [AutoMapper](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Getting-started.html) and to perform the [expressions](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Expression-Translation-(UseAsDataSource).html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as you and i fixed it like this with EF:

```
var viewModeValue = dbContext.Model.Select(m => new ViewModel{Field = m.Field}).Where(predicate) //predicate is an Expression<Func<ViewModel, bool>>
```

Entity Framework knows how to build the correct sql command. Converting the expression is much more complicated, because it is built to be immutable and could cause undesired run time effects if you do something wrong, and, in my case at least, it is not needed.