# Expression<Func<in T, bool>> or Expression<Func<TBase,bool>> to Expression<Func<T,bool>> Converter

Tags: c#, generics, expression-trees

Is there any simple way to convert

```
Expression<Func<TBase,bool>>
```

to

```
Expression<Func<T,bool>>
```

where T is inherited from TBase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as T derives from TBase, you can directly create an expression of your desired type with the body and parameters of your original expression.

```
Expression<Func<object, bool>> x = o => o != null;
Expression<Func<string, bool>> y = Expression.Lambda<Func<string, bool>>(x.Body, x.Parameters);
```

Answer (score 2):

You may have to convert manually. The reason for this is that you're effectively converting to a subset of what it could be. All `T` are `TBase`, but not all `TBase` are `T`.

The good news is that you can probably do it using [Expression.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355170.aspx), and apply the appropriate cast/conversion to `TBase` manually (of course catching any type safety issues).

Edit: I apologize for misunderstanding the direction you wanted to go in. I think simply converting the expression is still your best route either way. It gives you the ability to handle the conversion however you want. [Marc Gravell's answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/654153/c-how-to-convert-an-expressionfuncsometype-to-an-expressionfuncothertype) is the most compact and clear way I've seen to do it.

Comment: why manually? I convert E<F<Tbase,bool> to E<F<T,bool>>, so in every place where I use TBase I can use T.

Comment: That's my bad. I misunderstood the direction you wanted to conversion to go. My original answer is updated with a link to a better answer than I would be able to come up with.

Answer (score 0):

To make this I wrote ExpressionVisitor with overloading VisitLambda and VisitParameter

Here it is:

```
public class ConverterExpressionVisitor<TDest> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitLambda<T>(Expression<T> node)
    {
        var readOnlyCollection = node.Parameters.Select(a => Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDest), a.Name));
        return Expression.Lambda(node.Body, node.Name, readOnlyCollection);
    }

    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        return Expression.Parameter(typeof(TDest), node.Name);
    }
}

public class A { public string S { get; set; } }
public class B : A { }

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Expression<Func<A, bool>> ExpForA = a => a.S.StartsWith("Foo");
    Console.WriteLine(ExpForA); // a => a.S.StartsWith("Foo");

    var converter = new ConverterExpressionVisitor<B>();
    Expression<Func<B, bool>> ExpForB = (Expression<Func<B, bool>>)converter.Visit(ExpForA);
    Console.WriteLine(ExpForB); // a => a.S.StartsWith("Foo"); - same as for A but for B
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```